# get Minute and Second in android Timer

Tags: android, timer, android-edittext

I have a simple Timer and it's work with onTick method. I have two TextBox for minutes and seconds, but it crashed when one of them is empty. how can I manage this two TextBox? 
this is my code in onClick method for my Start Timer button.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.startTimer:
            //If CountDownTimer is null then start timer
            if (countDownTimer == null) {
                String getMinutes = minutes.getText().toString();//Get minutes from Minutes EditText
                String getSeconds = seconds.getText().toString();//Get seconds from Seconds EditText
                //Check validation over EditText
                if ((!getMinutes.equals("") && getMinutes.length() > 0)) {
                    int noOfMinutes = Integer.parseInt(getMinutes) * 60 * 1000;//Convert minutes into milliseconds
                    int noOfSeconds=Integer.parseInt(getSeconds) * 1000;//Convert Seconds into milliseconds

                    time = noOfMinutes + noOfSeconds;
                    startTimer(time);//start countdown
                    startTimer.setText(getString(R.string.stop_timer));//Change Text

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter no. of Minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Display toast if Minute EditText is empty
            } else {
                //else stop timer and change text
                stopCountdown();
                startTimer.setText(getString(R.string.start_timer));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.resetTimer:
            stopCountdown();//stop count down
            startTimer.setText(getString(R.string.start_timer));//Change text to Start Timer
            countdownTimerText.setText(getString(R.string.timer));//Change Timer text
            break;
    }
}
```

When getSeconds EdidtTex is empty, there is this Error in Log Cat:

**Error:**

08-17 07:48:26.402 3789-3789/amir.app.pro.my_timer2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                          at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
                                                                          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
                                                                          at amir.app.pro.my_timer2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

it refers to this line:

```
 int noOfMinutes = Integer.parseInt(getMinutes) * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: Please post the logcat of the exception, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the behavior of `Integer.parseInt()`, as this does not allow empty `String`s. You'll need to check whether the input is empty using `isEmpty()` before calling this method:

```
int noOfMinutes = getMinutes.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(getMinutes) * 60 * 1000;
int noOfSeconds = getSeconds.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(getSeconds) * 1000;
```